# When are ASP.NET MVC Controllers garbage collected?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, garbage-collection, controller

Once a controller object is created when does it become available for garbage collection?

Comment: Just curious: why do you care about this?

Comment: Just curious about how its all put together so that I wont run into any memory issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when no active reference to this object is detected. This is handled internally by the garbage collector and so you do not have to take care about it.

So, having this in mind, after the moment Page_Unload method is called which is hosting the controller, the garbage collector gets notified that the controller object is ready for disposal.

Comment: The part about not having active *references* is not really true at all. The CLR uses *reachability* to determine the need garbage collection, not reference counting. See Raymond Chen's blog for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx

Comment: @Eilon ... many thanks for the heads-up on my post - I will correct it asap :)