# Controllers created by System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory.CreateController are not disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, garbage-collection, controller-factory

I have created a class - `SystemConfig` - derived from `IControllerFactory` which I want to use to create Controllers.

In Global.asax.cs Application_Start(), I instantiate SystemConfig and register it:

```
var system = new SystemConfig();
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(system);
```

In `SystemConfig`, I implemented `CreateController`

```
public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext,
    String controllerName)
{
    switch (controllerName.ToLower())
    {
        case "log": return new Controllers.LogController();
        case "account": return new Controllers.AccountController( args as needed );
```

This seems to work well. The endpoints exposed by `AccountController` (for example) process requests as expected.

But the controller that is new'ed in `CreateController` is never disposed. The memory used by the IIS process just grows and grows.

I produced a dump and examined it with WinDbg

```
  !dumpheap -type MyApp.Controllers.AccountController -stat
```

revealed that there were 4372 instances of `AccountController`.
The longer the application ran, the more controllers were left in memory

After 29 hours the App Pool is recycled and memory pressure is relieved, but this is not a good solution.

Why is the `AccountController` instance not disposed once the web request has been processed and a response returned to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code shown in the OP, the controller instances ought to go out of scope and get *garbage-collected* (which is not the same as getting *disposed*) [once they've handled requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432770/126014).

My guess is that

- either the real code looks different than what is shown here, so that some other code holds on to Controllers instances,
- or the Controller 'registers' itself with a dependency or global variable when it runs, e.g. by calling some method and passing `this` as an argument,
- or the Controllers start some long-running task (logging?) that never properly terminates.

If you want to *dispose* of the Controllers, you can let `SystemConfig` implement the [ReleaseController](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory.releasecontroller) method, but that's only relevant if Controllers actually implement [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.idisposable), or hold on to resources that do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mark.

At first I thought none of your suggestions fit.

But I had created AccountController as a singleton - SystemConfig instantiated it and kept it in a class member. Then in CreateController, I just returned the member.

But that produced the error: *A single instance of controller 'Controllers.AccountController' cannot be used to handle multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.*

So I just new'ed it on each call to CreateController

But as a singleton it needed to be kept apprised of changes in the configuration. So I had created a "Config" object that exposed an event "OnChange" and AccountController subscribed to it.

And that is what was holding onto AccountController

Since AccountController is no longer a singleton it does not need to subscribe to the OnChange event